# Homology of Hom and Hom of homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

In 'Homological Algebra' by Cartan & Eilenberg:

> (page 203)
>
> For complexes $X$ and $Y$, consider the map $\alpha':H^{p+q}(\text{Hom}(X,Y))\rightarrow \text{Hom}(H_p(X),H^q(Y))$. Let $h_1\in H^{p+q}(\text{Hom}(X,Y))$ with representative $f\in Z^{p+q}(\text{Hom}(X,Y))$, and $h_2\in H_p(X)$ with representative $z_2\in Z_p(X)$.
>
> Then $fz_2\in Y^q$ and $d(fz_2)=0$.

I could not see why $fz_2\in Y^q$ and $d(fz_2)=0$, which should follow directly from the definitions of those above groups. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you mixed up exponents and indices quite liberally in this question... There's a difference.

The map $f$ is a cocycle in $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ of degree $p+q$. So first, by definition of the degree in the chain complex $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$, it will map a $p$-cochain of $X$ to a $q$-cochain of $Y$.<sup>*</sup> So since $z_2 \in Z^p(X)$, $f(z_2) \in Y^q$. Second, since $f$ is a cocycle, it satisfies the equation $d_Y \circ f - \pm f \circ d_X = 0$. When applied to $z_2$, this reads $d(f(z_2)) - \pm f(d(z_2)) = 0$. But $z$ is a cocycle too, so $d(z_2) = 0 \implies d(f(z_2)) = 0$.

---

<sup>*</sup> If you're not satisfied, you should reread Chapter IV. In particular, they explain that if $T(-,-)$ is a functor contravariant in the first variable and covariant in the second (like $\operatorname{Hom}$), then for cochain complexes $A^*$ and $B^*$, $T(A,B)$ has a double grading with $T(A,B)^{(p,q)} = T(A^{-p}, B^q)$ (you need the minus sign because $T$ inverts the direction of the differential of $A$). And so the associated graded complex is has in degree $n$:
$$T(A,B)^n = \bigoplus_{p+q=n} T(A^{-p}, B^q),$$
which, when applied to $T = \operatorname{Hom}$, gives you the result.